# Read into Pandas a SQL query that contains intermediate temp tables

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I have a query that's structured as such

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
   ...
);

SELECT
   ...
INTO
   #Table1;

SELECT
   ...
INTO
   #Table2;

SELECT
   ...
FROM
   #Table1
      JOIN
   #Table2;
```

This is a gross over-simplification with a number of other processes to create indices on the temp tables, a number of CTE's, etc. but the structure is the same at the core. The last command is a `SELECT` of the final dataset I want after I build a number of intermediate `temp` tables where there is a `SELECT` without an output return, the reason I believe I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Is there a way to allow Pandas to store the result of the final `SELECT` in a dataframe as intended? I've added `NOCOUNT ON` as I've seen elsewhere to no avail. The connection I'm using is a pyodbc SQL server connection with `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` if a different one would work better.

I understand I could re-write everything to be a chain of CTE's, but it'd be a massive performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a warning message was being displayed with one of the aggregations, that was causing the issue. I resolved it with `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`